# Wrong Distance CLLocation

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationdistance

In this code I receive a wrong distance, _latitude and _longtitude are NSString.
Any suggestion to correct this?

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude = [_latitude doubleValue];
        coord.longitude = [_longitude doubleValue];

        CLLocation *anotLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
        _distancia = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([location distanceFromLocation:anotLocation]/1000)];
```

Comment: OK, for one, you don't automatically get a location once your location manager starts updating its location. You need to use the didUpdateLocations: delegate method to know when the location manager has updated the location. I your current code, [locationManager location] is actually probably returning nil.

Comment: Can you print out the values of each location (both lat and lon values) you get in the LLDB (debugger)?

Comment: Print of Xcode Debugger [link](http://www.penaz.com.br/img/buglocation)

Comment: did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

check out this singleton implementation of location controller

https://github.com/hackerinheels/locationcontroller

with this just call

```
    CLLocation *currLocation = [[LocationController sharedLocationInterface]getCurrentLocation];
```